# Custom Infopath form - Dynamically create controls dependent on user entry

Tags: infopath, custom-form, field-controls

I am creating an inventory form on InfoPath 2010 to be used in SharePoint 2010.
I need to dynamically generate controls (text boxes) for serial numbers which depends on the number entered into a quantity field.
e.g if quantity is 5, then 5 text boxes are created automatically for inputting their serial numbers.
etc

Please any suggestions.

P.S I am very new with infopath and don't know how to use code with it.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but better answer. It seems like you are converting a paper form into an Infopath form -- this paper form had a box asking 'How many widgets?' and you want the value entered there to dictate how many serial numbers you offer the user...

Why not do it this way -- use a repeating table or repeating section to gather any number of serial numbers... and use a calculated field to show the quantity of serial numberes entered.

Or think about it this way... why ask them how many they have, then give them only that many textboxes? In the act of entering the serial numbers, they give you the count!

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting rules on controls or sections and use the formatting rule. I would probably place my controls in a section and have those hide or unhide based upon the product selected.

For more information on to do this formatting take a look at this Microsoft article.
[Click Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/hide-or-disable-a-control-based-on-values-in-a-form-HP001096364.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Not exactly what I need but helps for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to InfoPath, but i think what you want to use is normal ASP.Net forms. In there it will be really easy to create new controls and also easy to persist the information.

Could be my lack of knowledge about InfoPath, but I don't think it is possible to do what you want to do in InfoPath. As you don't know the number of boxes for input you need from the start.